# Why is the ArrayAdapter doesn't have the set method like arraylist do?

Tags: android, listview

Well it seem i am having quite some trouble with my arrayadapter of strings. It seem there is no real way to only modify an item in the list. I had to delete and insert back the string to see changes appears. So my question is Why is the ArrayAdapter doesn't have the set method like arraylist do ? Why it do not have any easy way to change an element in the list ? In order to change an element is is an option to create a custom adapter based on BaseAdapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets see this sample code:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(items, context);
```

you can modify an item using:

> //    items.set(index,object);

```
items.set(0,"Hello New Value");

myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// to tell the adapter there's new values has been changed
```

Comment: I will have to try that but i think i already tried. It won't work i think you need to set the adapter back cause it have no idea you changed the list. It doesnt seem to keep references.  When you set the adapter back it remove any selection which is not the result i way unfortunally.

Comment: remember in your `getView` in the `Adapter`, always set the value outside the `null` check, like `if(converView==null){//do somthing}` after it set the value.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. I never tried to make my own adapter but couldnt you just make the set inside the adapter ?  such adapter.setItem(position, string) ? i have a good feeling that i will have to create my own adapter if i wish to modify an item inside.. I just want to know if that a "yes". Do you have any good exemple ?

Comment: http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/using-an-arrayadapter-to-control-a-listviews-data/

download the sample from here : http://www.box.net/shared/0jl89vn0h6

Comment: Do you have an exemple of implementing a BaseAdapter wish would show a list of string where we can actually modify string with a set method ?

Comment: in the `Constructor` of your `ArrayAdapter` , pass it the `ArrayList`, then implement in the `Adapter` a custom method called `set(int index,String value)` then change the `ArrayList` using it

Comment: It work with a class extending arrayadapter and a set method i implemented thanks a lots!